# Precision error in JScript?

Tags: dynamics-crm, javascript

I'm a jscript newbie and I've a problem.

I'm writing a script to validate an IBAN bank account number in Belgium. I need to replace some letters by their position in a searchstring and afterwards I convert this string into a number to take the modulo 97 test.

The first part goes well, but afterwards with the conversion from string to number, 10 is added to my number. I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

```
function checkIBAN() 
{
  var iban = crmForm.all.fp_iban.DataValue;

  if (iban != null)
  {
    iban = iban.substring(4) + iban.substring(0, 4);

    iban = iban.toUpperCase();
    var searchString = '0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    var pos;
    var tmp = '';

    for (x = 0; x < iban.length; x++) {
      pos = searchString.search(RegExp(iban.charAt(x),'i'));
      if (pos == -1)
        return false;
      else
        tmp += pos.toString();
    }

    alert(tmp); // Here my value is 735320036532111490

    var nr =parseInt(tmp);

    alert(nr); // Now my value seems to be 735320036532111500
    alert(nr % 97);   
    if (nr % 97 != 1)
    {
      alert('IBAN number is not correct !');
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, 735320036532111490 is simply too great a value to store in an int. It'll always be rounded:

```
alert(735320036532111490 / 10);
// alerts 73532003653211150
```

[Here's a solution that might work for you](http://www.smsrobot.com/2009/04/check-digit-calculation-iban-mod-97/).

Comment: Thanks for that link! I created a Javascript port that may be useful: http://jsfiddle.net/nDSmZ/

Answer (score 0):

Always specify the radix when using parseInt.

```
var nr =parseInt(tmp, 10);
```

For reference information: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt

Comment: this should be a comment, as it doesn't address the problem at hand

Comment: @David Hedlund +1 your comment - you're right. <Hangs head in shame>

Comment: still, as a comment, it'd be a good one. omitting radix is a very common mistake, and it can cause some very unexpected behavior